# only add comment permission for a document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, onedrive-for-business

I'm trying to use one drive for review document functionality.

I wanna know if there is any way by which we provide permission to "Add Comment" only, I don't want the user to be allowed to edit the document.
I'm using the [graph API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/permission?view=odsp-graph-online) for sharing the document, in which I can only find two roles i.e.

```
role: ["read", "write"]
```

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible.

As comments are part of the document, one needs permissions to modify the document in order to be able to comment.

Comment: Is there any way by which I can make this happen by c# app, because I'm going to open the document in desktop app.

Comment: Probably. If you're doing a custom app anyway, why not display the document read-only and store the comments somewhere else?

Comment: I want the comment specific to the section selected by the user. If I'll make the document as read-only, the user will not be able to select the section for comment. I want it to work the way it works.

Comment: Then my first statement stands: If you want to add comments, you need edit-permissions.

Comment: Okay, thanks !!

Comment: If this answered the question, feel free to mark the answer accordingly.